# Insertar registro en 2 o más tablas relacionadas MYSQL consola?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, insert

Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de introducir registros que tienen llaves foraneas. Estas son las 2 tablas que tengo que introducir registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis conocimientos actuales me dicen que para añadir un registro, sería, primero agregar la direccion:

```
 insert into Direccion(colonia,calle,numero,cp) values ("Las Flores","Robles","2", "60162");
```

y luego:

```
insert into cliente(nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM, idDireccion) values("Victor","Espino","apellido2",1);
```

Como puedo hacer para hacerlo más simple?

Comment: Esa es la forma correcta, a qué te refieres con más simple?

Comment: Vaya! jeje
me refiero a si se puede simplificar a una solo linea SQL, agregar los 2 registros relacionados, al mismo tiempo.
En el mismo insert del cliente, hacer el inser de la dirección.

Comment: Primero debes tener existente la llave primaria que posteriormente será usada como foránea